# How to get Lambda event/context/payload from custom Docker image?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Can we cURL an internal endpoint like with other services to retrieve metadata such as the Lambda event blob? Most search results are API gateway related or presupposing that you're using a Lambda base-image, neither of which are relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's this:

```
curl "http://${AWS_LAMBDA_RUNTIME_API}/2018-06-01/runtime/invocation/next"
```

However, there's more to deploying a customer Docker image for being run by Lambda than just picking one and referring to it.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-custom.html